Problem with apache passthrough (trying to "redirect" without redirecting)
I'm using an Apache server.
I want to show the content of site.com/site/{URI} when site.com/{URI} is accessed, but I don't want any redirects. also I don't have access to config files, only to .htaccess.
site.com -> site.com/site  
site.com/example -> site.com/site/example

I've already tried this but it doesn't work.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /site [L]


RewriteRule ^$ /site [L] only matches the root URL without anything behind it (i.e. site.com). I'm not sure how familiar you are with regular expressions (RegExp), but ^ denotes a match on the start of the string, and $ denotes a match on the end of the string. Together, ^$ only matches an empty string, which is why the rewrite rule will only match on your root URL and nowhere else.
It sounds like you want this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]

This includes a RewriteCond(ition) that makes the next rule apply only if the request URI (after root) does not start with /site. This avoids rewriting already correct URLs.
